# add resource files only for integration tests

Tags: flutter

I have an application which returns a file (an image, a pdf, etc..) to show on screen. In order to make the integration test standalone, and not depending on external resources, I'd like to add some test files as an asset, but just for testing purposes, without packaging when building a production bundle.
Is that possible?

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: I have an app that downloads a PDF and shows it on the screen. the PDF is represented by a `Uint8List`. The `Uint8List` is returned by a class implementing a repository pattern, which I can replace when testing with a mocked repo which returns a local repo pdf, or at least that's the idea

Comment: Have you tried simply putting the file in the test folder, or wherever, and trying to read it with `File`? I think once upon a time I had some tests using local "regular" files, I don't remember whether they were flutter or dart, and golden tests are working based on the files they generate and keep this way. Idk if faking an asset is possible, but the way you have done the injection should allow for just reading the file and passing it to whatever you need.

Comment: I think I can't: I'm performing a e-2-e test (well, a golden one) and the way it works means compiling the whole project and running it on a device (virtual or not): this means I can't access the test folder itself :(

Comment: @Bertuz did you figure out how to include test files as assets?

Comment: No, I've work-arounded it with a public pdf on the internet. a good alternative could be setting up a docker with files served from it, but that wouldn't work for e-2-e tests running on platforms like firebase